# No kernel for grammar JavaScript found

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, hydrogen

windows 10
atom
hydrogen

get the following error message when try to run hydrogen.

> No kernel for grammar JavaScript found
>
> Check that the language for this file is set in Atom and that you have
>   a Jupyter kernel installed for it.

What to do to get hydrogen working ?

Comment: have you followed the [installation instructions](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Installation.html)?

Comment: including *Note that if you install a new kernel, you'll need to run Hydrogen: Update Kernels for Hydrogen to find it*

Comment: yes, i have followed the installation instructions as best i can.  Does not work for Atom on Windows 10...

Comment: Hydrogen: Update Kernel results in an error that no kernels are installed. I definitely have ijavascript installed. Setting the Language mappings to {"javascript":"JavaScript","ijavascript","JavaScript"} doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is posted here:
[No Kernels Installed](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1261)

In particular, the final solution is to update kernel.json accordingly:

```
{ "argv": [ "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ijskernel.cmd", "--hide-undefined", "{connection_file}", "--protocol=5.0" ], "display_name": "Javascript (Node.js)", "language": "javascript" }
```

Answer (score 0):

after installing javascript kernel with

`npm install -g ijavascript`

you also need to run `ijsinstall` in terminal.

Otherwise `Hydrogen: Update Kernels` won't be able to find the new javascript kernel.